# Why error #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'cat_rapoarte'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, phpmyadmin

I'm working on a student->parent->teacher grading system for the school I work at and while using MySQL I have received this error. Why?

```
SELECT `cat_materii`.* 
    FROM `cat_rapoarte` 
INNER JOIN `cat_rapoarte` on
`cat_materii`.`m_id`=`cat_rapoarte`.`rap_m_id` 
    WHERE `cat_rapoarte`.`k_id` = '7fbXe1dvltedEkIXELc8Q1NeMkKRb3pi' AND (data BETWEEN '2015-11-01' AND '2015-11-30') GROUP BY `rap_m_id`
```

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: @simeg the error is actually in the question title. Took me a while to spot it too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had the same table twice in the `join` clause. See the commented part in the query.

```
SELECT `cat_materii`.* 
FROM `cat_materii` --`cat_rapoarte` 
INNER JOIN `cat_rapoarte` on `cat_materii`.`m_id`=`cat_rapoarte`.`rap_m_id` 
WHERE `cat_rapoarte`.`k_id` = '7fbXe1dvltedEkIXELc8Q1NeMkKRb3pi'
AND (data BETWEEN '2015-11-01' AND '2015-11-30') 
GROUP BY `rap_m_id`
```

Comment: Thanks man!! It works perfectly! Can't believe it was such a stupid mistake! x_x